# how get a revert message

Tags: solidity, message

I have this example contract.

```
contract Example{
    function foo(){
        revert("hello world!!!");        
    }
}
```

When execute the foo function, this revert the tx, how get the revert message?

PD.: i use truffle to test contracts

---

now truffle support revert message

Comment: how can I catch a revert message in truffle?

Answer (score 0):

This feature still not supported on high-level: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/1686

Comment: i try this in remix and get this:
transact to Example.foo errored: VM error: revert.
revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Reason provided by the contract: "hello world!!!". Debug the transaction to get more information.